# How to check if particular set of key and value exists in a hashtable

Tags: c#, hashtable

```
public  DateTime LoggedOn = DateTime.Now;

Hashtable hash = new Hashtable();

string message = Test;

(hash.ContainsKey(message) && Convert.ToDateTime((hash[message])) == Convert.ToDateTime(m_LoggedOn))

{

 hash.Add(message, m_LoggedOn);

}
```

I want to add string message Test in every minute. Lets how to check it. Lets say my hashtablecontains string message Test and logged on time 21.11.2016 13:14:46
then ADD- Ok.

Again I want to add same message lets say if entered one minute 21.11.2016 13:15:46 or seconds or may be day.

Comment: At least add code which compiles.

Comment: You should use some kind of dictionary list instead as they are more efficient than the olde hashtable

Answer (score 0):

You can not add same keys into an `Hashtable`.

```
var hashTable = new Hashtable();
hashTable.Add("Test", DataTime.Now);
hashTable.Add("Test", DataTime.Now); //Will throw exception
```

How about you use something along these lines:

```
string key = uniqueStringKey;
var dict = new Dictionary<string, DateTime>();
dict.Add(key, DateTime.Now);
```